# Programmatically Update products attribute by sku for all store view

Tags: magento2, importexport

I am using below code to update product by **sku** but that is updating price for english store only , i will price of product to get updated in all store view .
    getObjectManager();

```
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'A960-CQ');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($collection as $product) 
{
    $product->setData('name', 'test description');
    $product->save();
    echo "Product Updated". " ";
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: no error but record is not getting uupdated

Comment: no error but record is not getting uupdated

Comment: hi jjust noticed above code changes data of my english store view , how to make it work for all store view

Comment: you have to get the store id and loop through it

Comment: refer from this https://mage2-blog.com/magento-2-change-product-status-programmatically/

Comment: can you modify my above code so it wors for all store

Comment: okay wait . I'll check

Comment: @user1799722 I am facing the same problem too. Have you find the issue and fix? Please help me

Comment: below solution worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can used below code to update product attributes for all store
**`Added $ for obj`**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeIds = array_keys($storeManager->getStores());
$action = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action');
$updateAttributes['name'] = "test";
$updateAttributes['price'] = 100;
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'A960-CQ');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($collection as $product) 
{
    foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
        $action->updateAttributes([$product->getId()], $updateAttributes, $storeId);
    }
}
```

We can use “**updateAttributes**” method to update Specific Attribute for product instead update all the data

You can pass multiple attribute that you want to updates detail.As show price and name are pass in an array and updateAttributes will update the name and price of the product

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution but didn't work for me. I'm using magento version 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

> You can use this code to update product data for all store

```
$sku = 'sku1';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $obj->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->get($sku,true, 0, true);
$_product->setPrice(100);
$_product->setShortDescription('short description');
$_product->setCustomAttribute("abc", 'abc');
$_product->save($_product);
```

Comment: Note: Relying on the product model to save itself is a deprecated practice.