# Create attribute for several product

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, eav-attributes

I have many hundred products and I want to create a product attribute to apply to all of them but with different value.

But I don't want to change the attribute product by product, it would take so much time.

How can I do that ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261160/programmatically-update-products-attribute-by-sku-for-all-store-view try this..

Comment: No way to do this in backoffice ?

Comment: then you need to export the product and update the attribute value in that excel sheet and import it...this is the way to do from backoffice

Comment: Hmmm... This could take a few time... Programmaticaly is better. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found answer directly in back-office

1. Go to Catalog -> Products
2. Select your products
3. In " Action " select "update attributes"

And that's it, you have the list of your attributes directly. You can update all product through this if you want.