# Update Product Attribute Data for All Store Views

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, programmatically

I'm trying to update a certain attribute of all of my products programmatically. So far, I've used `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` and iterating through the products, setting data and using `save()` on each product. This was successful, but just for the primary store view (ID 1) but not globally or for any of the three other multistore views.

I've tried calling `$product->setStoreId(0)` on each product, but this doesn't work.

What's the best way to programmatically update an attribute for all views?

Comment: Please try with this - https://www.cadence-labs.com/2018/03/magento-2-use-default-value-store-view-scope-fix/

Comment: This seems to be a Magento bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17284 Or did anyone magaged to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeIds = array_keys($storeManager->getStores());
$action = objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action');
$updateAttributes['name'] = "test";
$updateAttributes['price'] = 100;
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'A960-CQ');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($collection as $product) 
{
    foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
        $action->updateAttributes([$product->getId()], $updateAttributes, $storeId);
    }
}
```

given as answer here

[Programmatically Update products attribute by sku for all store view](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261160/programmatically-update-products-attribute-by-sku-for-all-store-view)

Comment: This successfully updated the attribute for each store, but not for "All Store Views".

Answer (score 0):

Somehow (from my perspective) Product doesn't match the semantics of most other parts of Magento - maybe there is legacy support in there or something because for product both ResourceModel and Repository both have different saving logic than other models like Block in module-cms.

Try the class `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action->updateAttributes()`, you can specify storeId there

I also had the same issue with products saving attributes to the wrong storeId with other methods